# transition different states of d3 stack layout

Tags: d3.js

I'm having trouble transitioning between different states of a stacked bar chart (created using `d3.layout.stack`).

I have been analyzing the transitions and joins in both [The General Update Pattern III](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234) as well as the older but fantastic [Bar Chart Tutorial 2](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html).

I'm stuck at a high level, conceptually. One is that two datasets need to be transitioned: the *amount* of stacks as well as the *value* for each stack. That is, on the one hand I may have 3 stacks turning into 4 (or 2). And on the other hand, I could have the 2nd stack's value changing from 15 to 18.

Are there any examples out there of stacked bar charts transitioning between different numbers of stacks as well as different values for the stack?

If I get close, and have code to attach, I'll do so. For now I'm still at the conceptual level. I wonder if `d3.layout.stack` isn't going to work and I'll have to go a different "stacked bar chart" route in d3 like in [this block](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208).

UPDATE

Here's my code so far, interspersed with my questions. As it's kinda long, I've removed all but what I think is necessary. FWIW, the code shows the new data, it just doesn't transition.

Also, I'm aware that it doesn't really make sense to try to change the `y` value and `height` value in the UPDATE transition as the data doesn't have those since we're still up at the "category" level of data, and not down at the "category's values" level. I suppose I'm trying things out and putting in seams (functions) where I can add console logs to add breakpoints. All this is to try to understand the flow of data.

```
drawChart: function(data) {
    var that = this,
        histogramContainer = d3.select(".histogram-container"),
        histogramContainerWidth = parseInt(histogramContainer.style('width'), 10),
        histogramContainerHeight = parseInt(histogramContainer.style('height'), 10),
        width = histogramContainerWidth,
        height = histogramContainerHeight,
        layers, yScale,
        then = new Date(), now;

    this.stack = d3.layout.stack()
        .values(function (d) { return d.values; })
        .x(function (dd) { return dd.timestamp; })
        .y(function (dd) { return dd.value; });

    layers = this.stack(data);

    yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, this.maxY * this.yHeader])
        .rangeRound([0, height * this.yHeightScalor]);

    var svg = histogramContainer.append("svg")
            .attr('class', 'chart')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .call(zoom)
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin.left  + ' , ' +
                  (height - this.margin.bottom) + ')');

    var clipPath = svg.append("clipPath")
            .attr("id", "clip")
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", (-height + this.margin.bottom + this.margin.top))
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height - this.margin.bottom - this.margin.top);

    var chartBody = svg.append("g")
            .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

    // Add a group for each layer
            // TRYING TO JOIN ON CATEGORY NAME
    var nameGroups = chartBody.selectAll("g.name")
            .data(layers, function (d) { 
                return d.name;
            });

    // UPDATE
    nameGroups.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("y", function(d) { return height - yScale(d.value) - .5; })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return yScale(d.value); });

    // ENTER
    nameGroups.enter().append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "nameGroup")
        .style("fill", function(d,i) {
            var color = (that.colors[d.name]) ?
                    that.colors[d.name].value :
                    Moonshadow.helpers.rw5(d.name);
            return "#" + color;
        })
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("y", function(d) { return height - yScale(d.value) - .5; })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return yScale(d.value); });

    // EXIT
    nameGroups.exit().remove();

    var rect = nameGroups.selectAll("rect")
            .data(function (d) { return d.values; })
            .enter().append("svg:rect")
            .attr("class", "stackedBar")
            .attr("x", function (d) { return that.xScale(d.timestamp); })
            .attr("y", function (d) { return -yScale(d.y0) - yScale(d.y); })
            .attr("width", this.barWidth)
            .attr("height",function (d) { return +yScale(d.y); });
```

UPDATE

Here's a bit about my data:

I transform the JSON I receive into something that d3.layout.stack expects. Namely, an array of objects each of which have a category name and a values array - the objects in the values array are an x value (a timestamp) and a y value (a simple integer value). For example:

```
data = [{ name: "Pete Peterson"
          values: [{ timestamp: 1394064493342,
                     value: 3 },
                   { timestamp: 1394064502343,
                     value: 5 },
                   ...]},
        { name: "Mary Jones"
          values: [{ timestamp: 1394064493342,
                     value: 0 },
                   { timestamp: 1394064502343,
                     value: 7 },
                   ...]},
        .....]
```

Comment: The best approach is to think of it from an [object constancy](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/) perspective.  What is staying the same, what is changing?  Are you re-grouping individual values into different categories?  Or are you updating data within existing categories?  You might want to do a two-stage transition (e.g. change width and x position first, then height and y position) to make it easier to track, but I'd need to know more about your data to offer specific suggestions about what approach would make the most sense.

Comment: Sometimes I'm adding and removing categories and sometimes I'm updating data within existing categories. And sometimes both at the same time. It doesn't seem like the x position needs to change - all changes should be in the y positioning. (and thanks!)

Comment: Make sure you're using a key function to keep your categories consistent, for one thing.  For entering categories, you'll want to figure out a starting position based on where they would be as a zero-height element in the previous stack, and then transition to new position and height: Fairly easy if new categories always go on the top of the stack, trickier otherwise.  I wasn't sure whether the number of stacks would be changing as well, which was why I suggested that you transition the stack positions (i.e., x/width) first and then transition the values within each stack (y/height).

Comment: Hmm. I hadn't thought of figuring a starting position for entering categories. I suppose they'll all enter at y = 0 (in a standard Cartesian coordinate system). Also, new categories could go anywhere which makes things tricky. While the number of stacks will change at some point, I'm assuming they won't for this first stage of 'getting things to work'.

Comment: (dunno if we should go to a chat room about this but..)
I'm using a key function but I can't see how that'll work. I select the data using the key of the category name. But the y values are a sub-dataset (if I can use that word) of the category. It's almost as if I need to say something like "if this category exists then do the following transition to all of it's stacks". In a sense, the first data join (on categories) seems to need to instruct the second data join (on stack height/yvalue).

Comment: Can you post more information about your data structure?  It may be easier to handle it yourself instead of using d3.layout.stack.  (To clarify, the stack layout expects the data to be organized in *layers*, with each layer then having values for each x position, it may be easier conceptually to organize your data in *stacks*, with each stack having multiple values.  That's what I was thinking of in the comments above...)

Comment: Thanks again @AmeliaBR, and I'll update the post with info about my data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having taken a closer look at the `d3.layout.stack()` code, my honest answer for how I would handle transitioning a stacked bar graph with changing data categories is that I wouldn't use `d3.layout.stack()`.  The amount of data manipulation to get the data in the format it expects is a much work as it saves by calculating the partial totals.

***But***, you say you've already got the data in the correct format, and only need to go from there.  Working from your code, with comments and corrections:

```
drawChart: function(data) {

/* // All this should go in a separate initialization function, distinct
   // from the function for drawing and updating data
    var that = this,
        histogramContainer = d3.select(".histogram-container"),
        histogramContainerWidth = parseInt(histogramContainer.style('width'), 10),
        histogramContainerHeight = parseInt(histogramContainer.style('height'), 10),
        width = histogramContainerWidth,
        height = histogramContainerHeight,
        layers, yScale,
        then = new Date(), now;


    var svg = histogramContainer.append("svg")
            .attr('class', 'chart')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .call(zoom)
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin.left  + ' , ' +
                  (height - this.margin.bottom) + ')');

    var clipPath = svg.append("clipPath")
            .attr("id", "clip")
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", (-height + this.margin.bottom + this.margin.top))
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height - this.margin.bottom - this.margin.top);

    var chartBody = svg.append("g")
            .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

    this.stack = d3.layout.stack()
        .values(function (d) { return d.values; })
        .x(function (dd) { return dd.timestamp; })
        .y(function (dd) { return dd.value; });

*/

    layers = this.stack(data);

/*  //Make the scales chart properties, and set the range in your initialization function
    yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .rangeRound([0, height * this.yHeightScalor]);
*/  
    this.yScale.domain([0, this.maxY * this.yHeader])


    // Add a group for each layer, using a key function to match
    var nameGroups = chartBody.selectAll("g.name")
            .data(layers, function (d) { 
                return d.name;
            });
/*
    // attributes "y" and "height" are meaningless on <g> elements
    // UPDATE
    nameGroups.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("y", function(d) { return height - yScale(d.value) - .5; })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return yScale(d.value); });
*/

    // ENTER
    nameGroups.enter().append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "nameGroup")
        .style("fill", function(d,i) {
            var color = (that.colors[d.name]) ?
                    that.colors[d.name].value :
                    Moonshadow.helpers.rw5(d.name);
            return "#" + color;
        })
/*  // It's not relevant here (since this code doesn't do anything), but in general, 
    // if you put your .enter() chain *before* the update chain, 
    // the newly added elements will become part of the main selection
    // and will have their attributes set along with the updating elements
    // so you only need to set *initial* values on enter
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("y", function(d) { return height - yScale(d.value) - .5; })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return yScale(d.value); })
*/;

    // EXIT
    nameGroups.exit().remove();
/*  //This will remove all the rectangles immediately.  If you want to transition
    //the rectangles for removing groups, you need a separate transition like

    nameGroups.exit().transition().duration(750)
              .remove() //schedule the <g> elements to be deleted
                        // at the *end* of the transition
              .selectAll("rect")
              .attr("height", 0); //transition to nothing
               //you don't need to explicitly remove the rectangles,
               //as they will disappear when the parent <g> is removed
*/

    var rect = nameGroups.selectAll("rect")
            .data(function (d) { return d.values; });
    //split up the enter and update of the rectangles
    //(not worrying about exit, since the stack layout requires you to create a data object
    // for each x value, even if the value is zero, and you said x values aren't changing)

    rect.enter().append("svg:rect")
            .attr("class", "stackedBar")
            .attr("height", 0) //set initial values for vertical positions
            .attr("y", -yScale(0) );

    rect.attr("x", function (d) { return that.xScale(d.timestamp); })
        .attr("width", this.barWidth)
         //set the horizontal positions for both new and updating rectangles
         //(not worrying about transitioning horizontal, since you said it probably
         // wouldn't change on update)
        .transition().duration(750)
            .attr("y", function (d) { return -yScale(d.y0) - yScale(d.y); })
            .attr("height",function (d) { return +yScale(d.y); });
        //transition the vertical positions

}
```

That should work, but it will be a little messy with overlapping rectangles when you have new layers coming in on update.  To get smooth transitions, as I said in the comments, you'd need to figure out a better initial "y" value for each rectangle based on the old values for the adjacent rectangles.  One option is to track down the rectangle below it in the stack:

```
    rect.enter().append("svg:rect")
            .attr("class", "stackedBar")
            .attr("height", 0) //set initial values for vertical positions
            .attr("y", function(d,i,j){
                 var lower = d3.select(this.parentNode.previousSibling)
                               .selectAll("rect")
                               .filter(function(d2, i2){ return i2 === i; })
                 return lower.empty()? //no such element existed
                           -yScale(0) :  
                           lower.attr("y");
             });
```

This will work *only* if the order in which you are adding `<g>` layers to the DOM matches the stacking order of the rectangles from bottom to top.  Otherwise (if the layers are getting sorted so new ones aren't always added on top) you'd need to (a) go through your sorted data array to find the correct group and then find the group lower than it in the stack, and (b) keep a reference to your old `layers` object so you can find the appropriate starting position.

Comment: Wow. You're off the hook.
I've actually already got most of what you wrote taken care of (extracting drawChart and updateChart functions and adding this.yScale) but I'm pouring over the rest. If you don't mind, I don't understand the reasoning why I shouldn't be concerned about the exiting of the rectangles? Specifically how the omission relates to the structure of the stack layout?

Comment: That bit about keeping a reference to the layers object as well as accessing the entire (relevant) DOM from within attr functions is fantastic. I don't know if there's are formal terms for those techniques in the d3 docs but there should be...

Comment: For the first quesiton:  Rectangles belonging to exiting *layers* are taken care of in the `nameGroups.exit()` block.  So the only thing you have to worry about in `rect.exit()` is data for which you have a name but no data for that date.  However, for `d3.layout.stack()` to work, you need to have a data element for eeach layer for every x value, so you'll need to create 0-value data objects during your data manipulation stage.

Comment: I don't know how you'd describe it, but I've seen other examples that keep track of the old layout until you're finished transitioning the new one.  Make the last line of your drawChart function `this.oldLayers = layers`, then you can use `this.oldLayers` to reference the previous layout.  However, you'll need a check to confirm that the old layout exists, so you don't get errors the first time you draw.

Comment: [This forum post is the closest I found to a discussion on how to update nested selections](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/5AxgsKK31EA).  Beyond that, the [tutorial list on the Wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials) is a bit of a mish-mash, but there's lots of good stuff there.  Also go through the example gallery, some have good write-ups.  And search Stack Overflow for other people's questions and answers.